# DataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm my WinForms 2.0 application I'm using a DataGridView and a custom edit control within the current cell (IDataGridViewEditingControl).

The current cell uses my custom edit control that inherits from textbox and implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface. This control now registers to the TextChanged event in order to perform some validation logic while the value is edited and to the Leave event to apply some visual effects from the custom edit control to the DataGridView cell.

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
public class CustomerTextEditingControl : CustomerTextBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    ...
    protected override void OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView[_col, _row].Style.BackColor = BackgroundColor;
        dataGridView[_col, _row].Style.ForeColor = ForegroundColor;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's my problem now: While the cell's background is properly rendered in whatever color BackgroundColor might be, the text itself is always rendered in black, no matter what color ForegroundColor is. First I thought there might be another Style that applies to the cell's content, but I couldn't find anything there. So I'm puzzled right now :-)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Marc

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in there, can you see if the ForeColor is actually assigned to the Style ?

Comment: yes, the assignment is executed

Comment: Then this means something else overrides the ForeColor at a later point in the chain of events. Can you post a minimalist code that reproduces the bahavior so I can test on my side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: the DataGridView class was subclassed and the OnPaintCell method overridden. The only style attribute that was taken account of was BackColor ...