# (datagridview) update a row's font color base on a column value

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to ask how a row auto update its font's color base on a column's value in `dataGridView`.

For example, a table has 4 columns that are: `id, name, rentPayMent and check`.

Check for each row to see if any of the value of `check == 0` 
If yes, then this row's font `color = red`  Else `do nothing`

at the movement, i use the code as following, but it bring out error with

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object,System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == "0") //**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;  //then change row color to red
        }
    }
}
```

**Thanks for all, i got the solution already.**

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim() == "0")
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Red };
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Style = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I Think You Should Refar This Link My Be Help You 

[staskoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202751/how-can-i-make-a-datagridview-cells-font-a-particular-color

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Orange, BackColor = Color.Blue };
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that on winform.

try my code below:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                if (row.Cells["YourDatagridColumnName"].Value.ToString() == "0") //if check ==0
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;  //then change row color to red
                } 

            }

        }
```

Best Regards

Comment: i got error message, not Column named check cannot be found.
Parameter name: columnName, even i try to change the column name to id or name, it still give me same warning.

Comment: Please see my updated post. You must set existing datagrid column.Make sure that your Column DataPropertyName and HeaderText is equal.

Comment: still has same problem, could not found the check, even i use the check instead of "YourDatagridColumnName", and i have set existing datagrid column.and the Column DataPropertyName and HeaderText is also equal

Comment: can you post also your select query that you used as your datagrid datasource

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to this:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()))  // make sure the value is present
        (
          if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == "0") 
          {
              row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;  //then change row color to red
          }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's preffered to name the columns in the dataGridView. for example name the column check as colCheck.
Use the CellFormatting method to change the row font color as follows

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["colCheck"].Index)
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {

                if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colCheck"].Value.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally would handle this logic using JavaScript. But if it's an absolute must to have it in the CodeBehind, I would check to see if the cell has a value of "0". If it does, I would add a CssClass of "red" (or whatever name you choose) and then write the CSS to have the color value. This will at least make it easier to maintain instead of having the color being handled Server Side.