# Selecting entire row in DataGridView programmatically (without using ...Rows[].Selected)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been trying to create Mp3 list using DataGridView to show info. I want to add data at runtime and I have Columns like Artist, Song Name, Rating, Path... but I want to be able to select entire Row when selecting a Cell. I've used this code for that:

```
    private void DataViewGrid1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int rindex = DataViewGrid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        DataViewGrid1.Rows[rindex].Selected = true;
    }
```

and it works but the problem is that it's to sloooow! When I click on the cell whole row is selected but it's visually terrible. I can see cell selected and after a delay whole row is selected but the delay is just too long. Is there a faster (or better) way to do this? Or maybe there is a better control that can do this? I also want to be able to present rows in a different font (for example: change font color for the same artist in the list).
I'm open for all suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
DataViewGrid1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

The entire row will be selected by clicking its row's header or a cell contained in that row.

If you want to color based on having a value in the cell, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203065/115272) will do the trick.

Comment: That was helpful but... First time I click some cell in the grid, it selects and then deselects that cell (very quickly) without selecting a row. Any other time (click) it works good. Any idea why is that happening?